# Efficient Numpy slicing on 3d array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to find the most efficient way to do slicing for a 3D numpy array. This is a subset of the data, just for test purposes :

```
in_arr =np.array([[[0,1,2,5],[2,3,2,6],[0,1,3,2]],[[1,2,3,4],[3,1,0,5],[2,4,0,1]]])
indx =[[3,1,2],[2,0,1]]
```

I need to get the value at the indx as stated. For example, indx[0][0] is 3, so I am looking for the 3rd elem of in_arr[0][0], in this case, 5.

I have the following code that will do what i need it to do, but the time complexeity is n^2, which I am not happy about.

```
list_in =[]
for x in range(len(indx)):
    arr2 = []
    for y in range(len(indx[x])):
        arr2.append(in_arr[x][y][indx[x][y]])
        #print in_arr[x][y][indx[x][y]]
    list_in.append(arr2)
print list_in
```

I am looking for a very fast and efficient way to do the same task for a large dataset.

Comment: [Indexing docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) For a real answer, improve your example a bit. E.g. by adding a complete expected output for your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this efficiently using broadcasted arrays of indices; for example:

```
i1 = np.arange(2)[:, np.newaxis]
i2 = np.arange(3)[np.newaxis, :]
i3 = np.array(indx)
in_arr[i1, i2, i3]
# array([[5, 3, 3],
#        [3, 3, 4]])
```

What numpy does here is to effectively match the entries of the three index arrays, and extract the associated entries from `in_arr`: the reason for the `[:, np.newaxis]` and `[np.newaxis, :]` terms is that it reshapes the three arrays to be compatible via numpy's [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) rules.

Comment: yes, i was looking at this and I am now understanding it. Really appreciate your help.